# Package/Imports instantiating a global two times

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to move to package structure and am facing a problem where a global object is being instantiated twice, which is a problem. I know "import-will-run-the-module"-type questions are common, and apologize for asking what I suspect is a simple question, but I'm still baffled after hours of trying.

I'm copying this basic structure as I've seen it used in flask apps, with **`run.py`** sitting in a directory alongside a /myproject directory.:

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

/myproject contains the modules along with an **`__init__.py`**, which imports routes.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from myproject import routes
```

**`routes.py`**  in turn imports from mymodule.py:

```
from myproject.mymodule import myfunction
```

**`mymodule.py`** instantiates a class that *can only be instantiated once* (it's bound to an external process)

```
import OnlyASingle

myobj = OnlyASingle()

def myfunction():
    x = myobj.dosomething()
```

I've run with `python run.py` and the debugger, and get an "already running" error from OnlyASingle.

The debugger tells me that mymodule is imported (and myobj is instantiated) first in line 1: `from myproject import app`of run.py, and then again when `app.run()` is executed. The second generates the duplicate instance error.

I've played around with `if __name__ == '__main__':` but find that  *_*name*_* is always equal to "_*main*_" in run.py, and it is always equal to "myproject.mymodule" in mymodule.py.

It's not clear to me if the problem is that `app.run()` is importing for a second time, or that I need to find another way to instantiate `myobj` to ensure it only happens once.

Any thoughts on where I've gone astray are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Although your project structure and imports are not clear enough, I think there is a way to prevent your global object from being instantiated every time you call/import it. You could use the so called **Singleton** design pattern for this purpose.

```
class OnlyASingle:
  _instance = None
  def __init__(self):
    # your initialization
    pass
  def __new__(cls):
    if cls._instance is None:
      # first time instantiation
      cls._instance = super(OnlyASingle,cls).__new__(cls)
    return cls._instance
  def do_something(self):
    print("foo")
```

When trying to instantiate new objects, the `__new__` checks if an object instance already exists and returns it instead of creating new objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought about this, and think it would work, but I have a feeling the problem has to do with the fact that the import seems to happen twice. Once from `from myproject import app` and again from `app.run()`. I don't understand why the second one is happening. If it would help, please let me know how I can describe the structure/imports more clearly. Thanks!